# How To: a required input on edit form, unchanged from default value, should be valid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

Here's an example of one of several inputs on a Create form (note `value` is empty). In this context the validation (query.validate.unobtrusive) works as expected requiring the user to fill in the required fields in order to submit the form.

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-8">
                <input class="form-control" id="LegalName" name="LegalName" type="text" 
                    value="" placeholder="Business Legal Name" 
                    data-val-required="Legal Name is required." data-val="true" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LegalName" 
                    data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

For the Edit form I use the same html but pre-fill each input with its current value (in this case `value="@Model.LegalName"`)

The problem is, even though each field is pre-filled with a value, the built-in validation prevents submitting the form, complaining that the required fields haven't been filled in.

The behavior I want is:

1. Any input on the page may be left untouched with its current
   value
2. Any input that the user changes must "pass" validation
   (e.g. nonempty, proper e-mail address)

For the Create case, the form validation feels "automatic" in that it just does the right thing. Is there a similarly "automatic" way to do this for the Edit case? Or do I have to do it manually (by coding the rules)?

Many Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... I'm an idiot today. The Form validation bit is working just fine. It's the Model binder that's got the issue... sigh.

That said, so it hasn't been a complete waste of time for you to read this there is a useful nugget here.

The Model used on this form contains, purely as a convenience, a class which has a couple of its own `[Required]` properties. Those properties aren't represented on the edit form so they were always coming back empty.

Thus, the moral of this story is: be careful using `[Required]` and similarly careful what you put in your View Models.